# permission denied if i want to connect to aws servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssh

I launched two Ubuntu free-tier servers in different regions on AWS. I was ping one server to another server but it displayed one error message that was connection timed out.can you please fix the problem as soon as possible.

This is the error:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
Permission denied (publickey).


    172.31.94.158 | UNREACHABLE! => {
        "changed": false, 
        "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.31.94.158 port 22: Connection timed out\r\n", 
        "unreachable": true
    }
```

I tried below commands

```
1.ssh-copy-id ubuntu@172.31.94.158
2.sudo ansible webserver -m ping
```

Comment: Are your security groups set up to allow one server to connect to the other?

Comment: "*can you please fix the problem as soon as possible*" - What am I, AWS technical support?

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way would be open port 22 on security group attached to the server for public IP of another server which it wants to connect.

if its simple test server and you want to check ssh connectivity for short duration and willing to delete server as soon as the test is done. then you can open ssh port publicly **"highly insecure"**